# Shared pointer from get() inside block

Tags: c++11

I am having some confusion with the following code snippet

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        int *iptr = new int(12); //create built-in pointer

        shared_ptr<int> s(iptr); //create shared pointer to it

        int *q = s.get();        //get built-in back using get (redundant step, but I was practicing)

        shared_ptr<int> (q); //Does NOT work without giving it a separate block ; error: conflicting declaration ‘std::shared_ptr q’ 

        //{shared_ptr<int> (q);} //This works!!

        return 0;
    }
```

My question is why one works while the other does not? What name does the one in the scoped block get? it seems to have no name if we follow the following syntax [`type name(args)`]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here isn't really about shared pointers, you've just mis-interpreted a bit of your own code. The line:

```
shared_ptr<int> (q);
```

is *not* a construction of an anonymous `shared_ptr<int>` using `q` as the constructor's argument. It is actually a declaration of a *named* `shared_ptr<int>`. You've really written:

```
shared_ptr<int> q;
```

which obviously won't compile since you're using the name `q` already in the same block. The commented-out code *will* compile since it's a different block, and the inner `q` will [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer `q`.

Also:

- You [should](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-newdelete) avoid using `new` directly. Use [`std::make_shared<int>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) instead.
- *Never* pass a pointer to memory that has another owner to the constructor of `std::shared_ptr<>`, since that constructor *takes ownership* of the memory, and will assume it can use it even if that memory has been released by the original owner.

Comment: Yep, I didn't notice the variable name was missing. +1

Comment: so it is like `Type name` (hence a declaration). In that case it would be `null` pointer and won't actually take the value of `iptr`. But the book (C++ Primer) suggests that it would have the address and hence delete the memory it refers when the block ends. Where does it get the `arg` from? PS: I am trying to add in the details here but it won't let me add newlines. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I got off track, @einpoklum got it right.

---

You cannot create more that one `shared_ptr` from the same *plain* pointer. All other `shared_ptr`s must be copies of another `shared_ptr`.

This is because `shared_ptr` must allocate another object that maintains a reference counter for your object, and `shared_ptr` constructor from a *plain* pointer does that. `shared_ptr` copy constructors just increment that reference counter.

When you create multiple `shared_ptr`s from the same *plain* pointer they allocate their own reference counters and end up deleting your object multiple times. Which leads to undefined behaviour (it often crashes on the second deletion).

---

There is also [`boost::intrusive_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#intrusive_ptr) that expects the reference counter to be inside the object. Hence, multiple `boost::intrusive_ptr` can be created from the same *plain* pointer because they all use the very same reference counter inside the object.

`boost::intrusive_ptr` is also more efficient than `shared_ptr` but it doesn't support weak pointers.

`boost::intrusive_ptr` is more efficient because it has the same size as a plain pointer (`shared_ptr`s size is double of that) because it doesn't have to allocate a separate structure with the reference counter and the deleter object elsewhere and keep another pointer to that.

In a multi-threaded application `shared_ptr` always uses more expensive atomic increment/decrement for reference counter maintenance, even if you never pass those pointers across threads. In a well designed application only `shared_ptr`s for certain `T`s get ever passed across threads and only those `shared_ptr<T>`s need to use an atomic counter. With `boost::intrusive_ptr` you only use an atomic counter for objects that do get passed between threads, and use a plain integer counter for the rest of your objects.

Comment: By 'can not' do you mean the compiler would give error or that it should not be done? Also can you comment on why does it work within separate block and not without it? Thanks!!

Comment: @User10482 The compiler won't tell you anything when multiple `shared_ptr`s are created from the same plain pointer, unfortunately.

Comment: @User10482 I got off track, einpoklum got it right.